# How do display Json data in HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" (click)="callJoke()">Get joke</button>
<h1>{{msg[1].joke.value}}</h1>
```

JSON data:

```
{  
   "type":"success",
   "value":{  
      "id":533,
      "joke":"The Chuck Norris Eclipse plugin made alien contact.",
      "categories":[  
         "nerdy"
      ]
   }
}
```

msg is an Object that im getting from API response

Comment: Try msg.value.joke since msg is not an array

Answer (score 1):

Try using an angular `json` pipe:

```
<h1>{{msg.joke.value | json}} </h1>
```